# DynamoDB delete table complete status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am deleting a table in DynamoDB using the following Javascript in Node.

```
var params = {
    TableName : "MyTable"
};

dynamodb.deleteTable(params, function(err, data) {
    // Not really done yet...!
});
```

I need to know when the table has actually been deleted. The callback doesn't indicate this, as it is still in the deleting process when this is called. Is there a way to know when the delete has completed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `waitFor` API can be used to check for the non-existence of table.

> Waits for the tableNotExists state by periodically calling the
>   underlying DynamoDB.describeTable() operation every 20 seconds (at
>   most 25 times).

**Sample code to delete the table and check for the non-existence of table using waitFor API:-**

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
    region : "us-west-2",
    endpoint : "http://localhost:8000"
});

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var params = {
    TableName : "country"
};

var paramsWaitFor = {
    TableName : 'country' /* required */
};

function waitForTableNotExists() {
    dynamodb.waitFor('tableNotExists', paramsWaitFor, function(waitForErr,
            waitForData) {
        if (waitForErr) {
            console.log(waitForErr, waitForErr.stack); // an error occurred
        } else {
            console.log('Deleted ====>', JSON.stringify(waitForData, null, 2));
        }

    });

}

dynamodb.deleteTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to delete table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(
                err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Deleted table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(
                data, null, 2));
        waitForTableNotExists();

    }
});
```

Comment: Wow, Saved my neck on Build server. Thanks.